# How to get the width of the console window?

Tags: c++, windows

I made a menu for a text adventure game I'm making. The problem is that the buttons go off the screen whenever the console size if different than the native 1920 x 1080. What is a function for getting the console window size?

Comment: If you do a search for e.g. `c++ windows console functions` in your favorite search engine, what information do you get then?

Comment: Text & Console & Buttons somehow do not combine correctly. Go for GUI.

Comment: @mic: Did you not ever use [Norton Commander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norton_Commander)? Or [Turbo Pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Pascal)?

Comment: By  buttons I mean text character art in the form of a button which i'm testing for mouse clicks and mouse position of that area

Comment: @IInspectable yes.... in 1990.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo`. You can create a short function to return the console rows and columns as:

```
#include <windows.h>

typedef struct {
    int rows, cols;
} winsz_t;

winsz_t *get_console_sz (winsz_t *wsz)
{
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);

    wsz->rows = csbi.srWindow.Bottom - csbi.srWindow.Top + 1;
    wsz->cols = csbi.srWindow.Right - csbi.srWindow.Left + 1;

    return wsz;
}
```

Comment: How would I use that in an if statement?

Comment: You would generally just declare a struct, e..g `winsz_t myconsole;` then call the function `get_console_sz(&myconsole);` to fill the struct members `rows` and `cols`. Then you can use `if (myconsole.cols > x) {...}` or however else you need to use `myconsole.rows` and `myconsole.cols`. You only need to make 1 call to the function to obtain the sizes, no need to make repeated calls to the function inside an `if(...)`. (unless the console size changes)